# TypeScript generic type with unknown

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

What does this statement mean?

```
type O<T> = T | unknown[]
```

In which case is `unknown` used and what does `O<T>` mean?

Comment: It's a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html). It says *"the value will either be of the type I supplied as `T`, or an array of who-knows-what"*.

Comment: When `unknown` is assigned, i know it's generic type union.

Comment: Then it's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Example `const a: O<string> = [{}, "something"];`

Comment: Thanks I was looking for an example. mentioning generic type `T` and provided other than that will use `unknown[]`

Answer (score 2):

Full description of `unknown`.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type

In short, anything can be assigned to `unknown`, but access to `unknown` requires type narrowing.

`O<T>` from your example means some T or array of unknowns.

```
let o: O<number> = 123;
o = [true, '123'];
if (typeof o === 'number') {
  const n: number = o;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly i was looking for.